# Yii - Prepend TextField Failed YiiBooster

Tags: php, yii

I use Yiibooster for my front-end, I put

`<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'email',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>25, 'prepend' => '@'//prepend text)); ?>`

in views/user/_form.php but the prepend text ('@') is not appear. Please help to solve this. Thanks for all.

Comment: Is it giving you any error?

Comment: no, there's no error. but the '@' is not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put into array. should be like this

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'email',array('class'=>'span5','maxlength'=>25),array('prepend' => '@')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php echo $form->textFieldGroup(
        $model,
        'url',
        array(
            'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'col-sm-5',

            ),
            'prepend' => '@',
        )
    );*/ ?>
```

Hope this will help.